# What do I need to do in order to make connection string work on win XP?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, connection-string

I have three PCs in my local network:

1. MS Server 08 - running sql server,
2. MS Win 7,
3. MS Win XP

I have written a program that uses connection string in order to connect to database that is working on first PC. Now, my program connects successfuly from the first PC and from the second one. I can connect to the first server PC through sql server manager from all three PCs. The problem is, that when I try to connect through my program from third PC, I am getting connection string error (it shows only on this PC).

So, what do I need to install on win XP in order to make it work?

Also, here is my connection string:

```
<add name="MyDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.14;Initial Catalog=AdData;User name=Name;Password=11111;" />
```

Edit: My firewalls on all PCs are disabled.
Edit2: Here is the exception message:

```
the provider did not return a providermanifesttoken string
```

Comment: "I am getting connection string error" isn't a very good fault report. What happens when you telnet to `192.168.0.14` on the listening port of your SqlServer instance (usually 1433)? Do you connect? Should this question be on http://www.serverfault.com instead?

Comment: @spender: Updated my post, also, I can successfully connect to my sql server using sql server management studio, I will try that telnet thing in a sec.

Comment: If SSMS is connecting, telnet probably will too... something else is probably wrong.

Comment: I'd try installing this:  (Not sure if its XP compatible) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937733.aspx

Comment: sqlncli.msi  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27596

Comment: @granadaCoder: Installed successfuly, but the error persists...

Comment: I like this tool for quick IP:Port "checks".     http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009

Comment: Are there any Inner Exceptions?  Make sure you traverse the entire exception tree.

Comment: @granadaCoder: The exception I posted in my post is the inner exception. The outer one is saying that there is a problem with connection string.

Comment: Data Source=192.168.0.14,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;      So you have a pretty "exact" connection string.  You can add the port (1433 in the example) and the network library.  Now....WAY BACK in 1999 or thereabouts, I had an issue on a NT 4.0 box not connecting because the default network library was using named pipes.  And putting in the extra tcp version fixed that issue.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530675/difference-between-these-connection-strings

Comment: @granadaCoder: I need to go out for a while, will try this out as soon as i get back! Thanks!

Comment: Wow.  Just had a 'nam like flashback.  Look at this msdn, it starts shedding some light on all the protocol voodoo.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328383      You may want to open the registry on a working XP box and the non working XP box and look around.      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\

Answer (score 1):

Create a udl file, if it connects then the problem is the code / application, if it does not connect, then it's your firewall, connections string, dll library etc. Well the important thing here is probably the connection string. Do the following: create an empty text file and rename it "myconnection.udl". Now double click on the file and it will launch an applet. You can configuer the connection to your database and test it. (it will pick up registered connection libraries etc). If it give OK, then open the udl file in notepad, you will see the correct connection string. Paste to your app connection settings. UDL files are generally misunderstood. They are simply a text file that holds the connection settings. They then call the connection dll. If the udl file works then you have a correct connection string 100%

Comment: This is fkin crazy, I did as you said, your answer is very logical, my .udl file connected successfully, I have copied connection string and still nothing!! What the hell, on all PCs it works and on this one it is not, wtf! Anyways thanks for input!

Comment: Well the UDL file will use the exact transport mechanism and ports that the commumication occurs over, furthe more you will be running it with the same permissions as your software. There is nothing special about XP. Are the other 32 bit or 64, its the program that is asking for further validation